# What exactly is this question asking: Deduce that the feld $\mathbb Z/(p)$ is not ordered, where $p$ is a prime.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Is it asking me to show that the set of all prime integers are not an ordered field? I fail to see how they would even be a field in the first place, seeing as they're not closed under addition or multiplication. Am I totally misunderstanding this question? What does the / mean?

Comment: You are totally misunderstanding the question. Before  you even start it, look back in your book and notes for the _definition_ of $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ and the proof that it is a field. Then you can proceed to think about whether it is an ordered field.

Comment: Do you know what an ordered field is? It should be right there before the question. Please include the exact question.

Comment: I looked thru the textbook and could not find a discussion about ℤ/(). Could you at least tell me what ℤ/() is in plain english, and I can just go from there? I wanted to look through lecture as well as I think it might have been discussed, but lecture was not recorded :(.

Comment: I know what an ordered field is, but I just don't know what ℤ/() is referencing. That is the question word for word

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is the *quotient ring* of $\mathbb{Z}$ by the *ideal* generated by $p$. In other words, it is the integers considered modulo $p$.

Comment: Ok THANK YOU that's exactly what I needed to know!